# Recognition of keyboard event in python

Tags: python-3.x, keyboard-events

I'm a beginning programmer and i need a way to get python to recognize a keyboard event. So far i can only find these methods in vPython or tkinter, and i want to simply use the normal python shell. if anyone can help me with a module name/where i could download a module for free that would be very helpful. or simply the code if there is no need for a module.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no generic "keyboard event", they all depend on what your environment is.

In a terminal there are no keyboard events at all, you simply get sent text on stdin. In Windows you need to use the Win32, on Unix you need to use the X11 API and on Mac you have to use whatever OS X uses is it Cocoa?). wxPython and tkinter all work on all these platforms to provide an API that works on all of them. And the same goes for other GUI toolkits of the same sort like KDE and GTK. So you should use one of those. Which one is a matter of taste, but since tkinter is included in Python, that seems the obvious choice.

You can call the respective API's for the respective platforms directly, but it's generally not worth the trouble.